# Is particular bookmark a content provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I know that **browser is content provider** but i want to know, is bookmark (which support to browser) is also a content provider.

Comment: I tihnk you should read the basics here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html it defines what a content provider is

Comment: i have already read that. Can you directly tell me yes or no.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware in android 6 [global bookmarks are removed](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser).

In general, any app can implement its own bookmarks and share it as content provider.
You may ask - but how do clients find provider? Well, it’s required to know the URIs of a provider to access it. The recommendation is to publish public constants for the URIs and document them to other developers.